# How to create conditional if statement based on value + wildcard in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, conditional-statements, wildcard

I have a string that may be either:

```
my_string = "part1"
```

or:

```
my_string = "part1/part2"
```

I need to handle each of the above scenarios conditionally ie (pseudo code):

```
if my_string = "part1/" + *:
    # do this
```

where * could be any value.

Once I can catch this condition, I will split `my_string` and assign the second part of the path to a new variable ie:

```
my_new_string = my_string.split("/")[1]
```

Is it possible to set up this sort of 'wildcard'?

**Edit:**

Actually, I just realised I could probably do something like:

```
if "/" in my_string:
    my_new_string = my_string.split("/")[1]
```

I'd still be interested to know about whether such a 'wildcard' operation exists.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is provided by the regular expression module. http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always use Regular Expressions to match the condition see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match

re.match(r'part1/.+', your_string)

Note the + instead of the * to make sure a string follows after the /